# Cambiar la condición de un campo al seleccionar una opción

Tags: html

Tengo un campo <`select`> con 2 opciones: si y no.

Al seleccionar la opción si, cargar un campo con una condición cuyo valor numérico no sea mayor a 20. Pero al seleccionar la opción no, cargar el mismo campo con una condición cuyo valor numérico no sea mayor a 165.

```html
<label for="" class="control-label" >NO / SI:</label>
<select class ="form-control" id="" name=""  required style="width: 76px;" >
<option selected value="">NO</option>
<option value="">SI</option>
</select>

<label for="">CANTIDAD</label>
<input type="number" min="1" max="169" class="form-control" name="" id="" placeholder ="#" required style="width: 85px;">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, vamos con el SELECT y el Input de Texto

```js
    $('#miselect').on('change',function(e){
        var opcion = $(this).val();
        if(opcion.localeCompare("si") != 0){
            $('#numero').attr({"max":20, "min":0});
        }else{
            $('#numero').attr({"max":165, "min":0})
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="miselect">
        <option selected disabled value="">Seleccione una Opción</option>
        <option value="si">Si</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type="number" min="1" max="169" class="form-control" name="" id="numero" placeholder ="#" required style="width: 85px;">
```

Lo que se hizo fue asociar un ID a los INPUT y SELECT para luego a traves desde jQuery obtener el valor del SELECT y actualizar el atributo del input tipo numero (max y min).

Pruebalo y avisas.

Comment: La respuesta es correcta, podrías hacer la respuesta ejecutable como en la pregunta con un Snippet (puedes revisar [¿Qué es Stack Snippet?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%c3%a9-es-stack-snippet)), también te puede ser de ayuda para futuras preguntas/respuestas.

Comment: Funciona pero si se escribe un numero mayor a 20 cuando se selecciona si, al seleccionar no, no lo deja en 20 lo deja en el valor que se escribió esto puede generar errores, edita la respuesta y pon una validación que por defecto si selecciona no, deje el valor del campo en 20 y lo limpias cada vez que cambie de opción